# Why does print line is invalid syntax? [python]

Tags: python, python-3.x, printing

```
#!/usr/bin/python
def creating_table():
mailingTable = open("mailingTable.txt", "r")
lines = mailingTable.readline()
for line in lines:
    print line
mailingTable.close()
```

It says print line is invalid syntax. Why? I m using python 3.3.5

Answer (score 4):

In Python 3.x, you have to write [`print()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#print) as follows, because now it's a function:

```
print(line)
```

In Python 2.x it was possible to omit the `()`, but that's no longer the case.

Comment: thanks, so much, omg, those little petty details

Comment: No problem. Be sure to check all the [differences](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3), it's important to know about them ;)